# Grid items coming in two rows instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and was trying to style components however I am having a problem:

Here is the output that I am getting:

[image]

I want both the 3 section columns in one row instead of two I am adding the grid items in grid container However I am still getting the output in two rows I want to bring them to one row How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
<GridItem
                xs={12}
                sm={12}
                md={12}
                style={{ paddingRight: "0px", paddingLeft: "0px" }}
              >
               <GridContainer>
                <Card style={{ margin: "0rem" }}>
                  <GridItem
                    xs={2}
                    sm={2}
                    md={2}
                    style={{
                      paddingRight: "0px",
                      paddingLeft: "0px",
                      margin: "0rem"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Card style={{ margin: "0rem" }}>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={7}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Order"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                        <GridItem
                          xs={5}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="item"
                            label="Item"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={12}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Ord Qty"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={12}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Cust CD"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                    </Card>
                  </GridItem>
                </Card>

                <Card style={{ margin: "0rem" }}>
                  <GridItem
                    xs={1}
                    sm={1}
                    md={1}
                    style={{
                      paddingRight: "0px",
                      paddingLeft: "0px",
                      margin: "0rem"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Card style={{ margin: "0rem" }}>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={12}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Order"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={12}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Ord Qty"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                      <GridContainer
                        style={{ marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px" }}
                      >
                        <GridItem
                          xs={12}
                          style={{
                            paddingRight: "0px",
                            paddingLeft: "0px",
                            margin: "0rem"
                          }}
                        >
                          <CustomOutlineInput
                            id="order"
                            label="Cust CD"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                    </Card>
                  </GridItem>
                </Card>
                </GridContainer>
              </GridItem>
```

Please help

Comment: You have the `material-ui` tag, but MUI `Grid` doesn't work like that. What's exactly the library you are using?

Comment: import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

Comment: @MatthewKwong I am using material ui Grid Grid item is a component I made using grid with spacing thats it

Comment: Then what is `GridContainer` and `GridItem`? Is it equivalent to `<Grid container>` and `<Grid item>`?

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: Then I suggest you NOT to do it, because in some cases, like a nested grid, you will be doing `<Grid container item>`.

Comment: is there a way you could show how to do this with an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239934/discussion-between-matthew-kwong-and-sambit).